# Best approach to create Tank_Auth in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I just installed Tank_Auth in Codeigniter and would like to develop a CMS and to know what is the best approach to create an admin account and client account. Do I have to separate one CI directory and controller for a public website and another CI directory controller for the Admin and Client auth?

Ex: My client has a website so everyone (public) can see the contents. It works fine. I want the admin, client and some of their associated to access Create, Update, Delete contents. How would I do that?

Comment: May be [this](http://johnwright.me/blog/tank-auth-groups-roles-admin/) could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the link you send and made a change but after the change, it loads into a blank page instead of the default 'tank auth' user login form.

How do I make a link to make it works?

Noticed this line

```
$this->load->library('tank_auth_groups', '', 'tank_auth');
```

Comment: Hi qpixo, I'm the author of the post linked to above ([tank auth groups](http://johnwright.me/blog/tank-auth-groups-roles-admin/)) . Yes you'll need to do steps 1 and 4 to get the zip file download working. Step 4 is the line you mentioned. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi JohnWright, for some reason, I can't make that work in my CI. I can't load that tank_auth_groups library. It can't call the defined function if!($this->tank_auth_groups->is_admin()) {...}

Comment: Oh I see. The problem is this... the code should be `if(!$this->tank_auth->is_admin()) { ... }` ... the line above `$this->load->library('tank_auth_groups', '', 'tank_auth');` loads the library as '$this->tank_auth' .  Since the class 'Tank_auth_groups' extends the class 'Tank_auth', this works fine.

Comment: also, make sure that this line `$this->load->library('tank_auth_groups', '', 'tank_auth');` replaces this line `$this->load->library('tank_auth');` everywhere in your code.

Comment: I just created an answer of my own on this thread and added the install instructions on github.

Comment: That's really weird. I did include $this->load->library('tank_auth_groups', '', 'tank_auth'); in my constructor then in function index() { if(!$this->tank_auth_groups->is_admin()) {...} It doesn't go in this condition. Then I was wondering in CI blocks any outside files of MVC directories. In this case, you must use $CI =& get_instance() instead of $this. I make this change still not working...

Comment: You are right, `$this->tank_auth_groups->is_admin()` won't work. You must change it to `$this->tank_auth->is_admin()` . This is your only problem.

Comment: I made a chance like you said, still not working. It doesn't go through the load library line. $this->load->library('tank_auth_groups', '', 'tank_auth');

Comment: I see. Hmmm, are you using CI 2.1.0 and Tank Auth 1.0.9 ? That is what I built the extension with.

Comment: I'm using CI 2.0.3 and the lastest Tank Auth version

Comment: I believe my CI version was the main issue :)

Comment: it could be... but actually I discovered a small bug in my code... it is fixed on github, but you can also open 'Tank_auth_groups.php' and change this line `require APPPATH . 'libraries/tank_auth.php';` to `require APPPATH . 'libraries/Tank_auth.php';`  .. Notice, it's just a capital "T". The case sensitivity could cause issues on some environments. Are you on Linux?

Comment: Just upgraded to CI 2.1, I'll let you know if working or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Now it's working great! :) Btw, I noticed in your blog you should update your question 4 and in Additional Resources; first letter to capital 'T': $this->load->library('Tank_auth_groups', '', 'Tank_auth');

Answer (score 2):

Hi using [Tank Auth Groups](http://github.com/wrightlabs/tank_auth_groups) you can achieve this (I've updated the README with install instructions). [This blog post](http://johnwright.me/blog/tank-auth-groups-roles-admin/) outlines how this code was created and how to create an admin base controller.